# How to show size and colors separately in shoplify?

Tags: shopify

I want to display colors and sizes separately on frontend to filter the collection in shopify. But when I do, it shows color and size in same variable with slash in it.

Here is the image

[image]

Here is the code that i try

```
      <div class="size-filter clearfix mt-4">
         <h4>SIZE</h4>
         <hr>
         {% assign available_sizes = '' %}
         {% for product in collections.frontpage.products limit: limit %}
         {% for variant in product.variants %}
         {% if variant.title != 'Default Title' %}
         {% unless available_sizes contains variant.title %}
         {% if  variant.available %}
         {% capture available_sizes %}{{ available_sizes }}, {{ variant.title }}{% endcapture %}
         <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input coll-filter" type="checkbox" value="{{variant.title}}" id=""
            {% if current_tags contains tag %} checked  {%endif%}>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="">
            {{variant.title}}
            </label>
         </div>
         {% endif %}
         {% endunless %}
         {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
         {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

Please help me to fix this error, i stuck here from last 3 days.

**Error Solved but got this output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do use the `options_with_values` object:

```
{% for product_option in product.options_with_values %}
  <h5>{{ product_option.name }}</h5>
  {% for value in product_option.values %}
    <input id="{{product_option|handle}}-{{value|handle}}" type="checkbox" value="{{ value }}" />
    <label for="{{product_option|handle}}-{{value|handle}}"></label>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But you will need to write some Javascript in order to tie it to the main select which holds the variants ids.

Comment: This code is not display anything, i want to show this in collection page

Comment: @RobinSingh whell you need to be in the product loop then `{% for product in collection.products %} the code will work here {% endfor %}`

Comment: One more question, it display size multiple times, how can i prevent that

Comment: @RobinSingh if you are referring to `<h5>{{ product_option.name }}</h5>` it should be displaying only a single time per option. Meaning that it should show Size -> all options under it and then Color -> all the options under it. I don't know what do you mean that it shows size multiply times.

Comment: please check the image above

Comment: @RobinSingh are you sure that one of your products doesn't have only a Size option?